# How to allow Cors Headers in Google AppScript for making an XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have created a `doGet` and `doPost` endpoints in my `appscript`. When I hit the endpoint to make a post request from Python, it does work perfectly and as expected.

But when I try to hit the same url with my Flutter based mobile App, it throws me an XML error. (Which I suspect is related to CORSING).

When I hit the url with `get request`, I get the right response, but `post` request is failing. To ensure that my Post request is properly configured, I have made a `post request` to public API and it worked like charm.

Is it possible to add headers, where I could enable cors like this:

```
allowHeaders = {
  "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*", // Required for CORS support to work
  "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true, // Required for cookies, authorization headers with HTTPS
  "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Origin,Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token,locale",
  "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "POST, OPTIONS"
}
```

Here is what my doPost request returns:

```
ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(
    {
      data: isAuthenticated.data,
      error: true, 
      //request: request,
      msg: query.apiKey,
      //paramters:request.parameters
  })).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
```

Here is my python script to get the post response:

```
requests.post("https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbz7kTROol8u509M_p9pMZ9XRnL-myVjcRQKeb9Etp_OIMPnH640vHf_0Jp2dvvrbto7kOg/exec",
                  json = requestObject)
```

And here is my Flutter function:

```
Future<http.Response> createAlbum() async{
  print("Trying to make a post request");
  var result = await http.post(Uri.parse('https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbz7kTROol8u509M_p9pMZ9XRnL-myVjcRQKeb9Etp_OIMPnH640vHf_0Jp2dvRIco7kOg/exec'),
    headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
    body: jsonEncode(<String, dynamic>{
      "apiKey":apiKey,
      "operationType":"register_user",
      "operationData": {
        "email": "shivam@yoptima.com",
        "otp": 318728
      }
    }),
  );
  print("Here is the result: " + result.body);
}
```

Just to clarify things:

1. Get Request works for both the platforms.
2. Post Request works with python for AppScript.
3. Post Request works for any other public API from flutter.
4. Post Request doesn't work for Flutter when Hitting AppScript API.
5. I suspect it to be something to do with CORS. (But not very sure).
6. Flutter `http` library makes request via `XMLHttpRequest`.

Comment: What is the error you get from Flutter?

Comment: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/XXX/exec' from origin 'https://www.YYY.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: According to [them](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/46904#issuecomment-810043177) it's not a flutter issue, but actually a part of web development. We have to configure the server side of your request to accept a [complex request](https://web.dev/cross-origin-resource-sharing/?utm_source=devtools#preflight-requests-for-complex-http-calls). But I can't find anywhere that tells you how to do that for Apps Script!!

Comment: I mean normal APIs methods like fetch and axios work well with AppScript, only when you try to call them flutter is when it starts to throw error

Comment: Can you confirm their WebApp deployment settings? I've noticed that most people who have gotten this to work have been executing it as "Me" and "Anyone" even anonymous is allowed to access it. Which doesn't has the CORS issue I believe

Comment: Yeah, it has executed it as me and allowed by anyone. which client are you using?

Comment: I'm using [google_sign_in](https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in).